# Strange output of Tikz-Feynman

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I used the hello,world example of tikz-feynman, which should draw a horizontal Feynman diagram

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b] { 
 i1 -- [fermion] a -- [fermion] i2, 
 a -- [photon] b,
 f1 -- [fermion] b -- [fermion] f2,
};

\end{document}
```

But got a strange output like

[image: Wrong feynman diaggram]

Can you help me?

Comment: Welcome! It is time to update your TeX installation, this bug has long been fixed.

Comment: And please compile with LuaLaTeX or use manual positions :)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I have upgraded TeXLive 2017 to 2020 and the problem persists.

Comment: @JP-Ellis I got no error message during the compling. Although it is not solved yet, thank you for making the lovely package.

Comment: Thank you. LuaLatex worked.

Comment: @user112002 There shouldn't have been errors in the log, but there should have been plenty of warnings telling you that some features do not work if you're not using LuaLaTeX.